# 'Entity' object has no value 'Width'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Alright, so i am trying to create a project where i can create a Red Rectangle that can Jump, however after, I am now getting the error "Entity has no attribute "Width."" I'd be lying if I said I 100% understood classes, but I believe that I am using it right. What am I doing wrong? I'd appreciate any advice on my code! Here is the code for my project.

```
# Imports--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

import pygame


# initialization-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

pygame.init()

# Flags----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

gameExit = False

# Variables -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

display_height = 500
display_width = 500
bg = (0, 0, 0)
isJump = False
# Colors --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

FUCHSIA = (255, 0, 255)
PURPLE = (128, 0, 128)
TEAL = (0, 128, 128)
LIME = (0, 255, 0)
GREEN = (0, 128, 0)
OLIVE = (128, 128, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 165, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
MAROON = (128, 0, 0)
SILVER = (192, 192, 192)
GRAY = (128, 128, 128)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
NAVY = (0, 0, 128)
AQUA = (0, 255, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

# Draw Screen----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

win = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Airbender Training")
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Mobs ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
class entity:
    #Entities will be every mob in the game
    def __init__(self, width, height, velocity, x, y, sprite):

        entity.width = self.width
        entity.height = self.height
        entity.x_position = self.x_position
        entity.y_position = self.y_position
        entity.sprite = self.sprite


player_width = 64
player_height = 64
player_velocity = 5
player_x_position = 5
player_y_position = 5
player_sprite = pygame.draw.rect(win, RED, (player_x_position, player_y_position, player_width, player_height))
    # ^This makes a placeholder red square^
player = entity(player_width, player_height, player_velocity, player_x_position, player_y_position, player_sprite)

# Functions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

def drawGameWindow():

    pygame.win.fill(bg)
    pygame.win.blit(player_sprite, player.x_position, player.y_position)
    Clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()

def jump():

    jumpCount = 1
    while jumpCount <= entity.height * 1.5:
        entity.y_position += jumpCount
        jumpCount += 1
    while jumpCount >= entity.height * 1.5:
        entity.y_position -= jumpCount
        jumpCount -= 1

# Main Loop------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event == pygame.k_RIGHT or event == pygame.k_D:
                player.x_position += 5
            if event == pygame.k_LEFT or event == pygame.k_A:
                player.x_position -= 5
            while not isJump:
                if event == pygame.k_up or event == pygame.k_SPACE:
                    jump(player)

    drawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: looks like simple typo.  Your `class` attribute is `width` not `Width`.

Comment: @Sociopath I looked over the code 10 times and can't find a capital Width anywhere, where is it?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm not sure if I follow, I need to make entity.width into self.width and set that equal to width.width?

Comment: Provide complete error message here. Without it it's hard to guess in which line error has occured.

Comment: There is neither an identity `Entity` nor `Width` in your entire code, so the error is probably *'entity' has no attribute 'width'* –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is neither an identity `Entity` nor `Width` in your entire code, so the error message is:

> 'entity' has no attribute 'width'

The error occurs in:

> ```
> class entity:
>     #Entities will be every mob in the game
>     def __init__(self, width, height, velocity, x, y, sprite):
>
>         entity.width = self.width
> ```

It has to be:

```py
class entity:
    #Entities will be every mob in the game
    def __init__(self, width, height, velocity, x, y, sprite):

        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.x_position = x_position
        self.y_position = y_position
        self.sprite = sprite
```

The fist parameter to the constructor (or any other non static) method is the instance of the object.

You want to assign the parameter `width` to the member `.width` of the object `self`. So it has to be:

```
<object>.<member> = <parameter>
```

```py
self.width = width
```

Note `entity` is the name of the class, but there is no object `entity`

Comment: Ah okay, I get it now! Thanks bud, you've really helped me out alot